# How to make binary tree from array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, binary-tree

I have an array `var array = [8,10,12,5,3,6];`

**Logic**

1. First node would be root node.
2. If new node value is less or equal `=<` than parent node, It would be left node of parent node
3. If new node value is greater `>` than parent node, It would be right node  of parent node

And I am trying to achieve output like below object:

```
{
   value:8,
   left:{
      value:5,
      left:{ value:3 },
      right:{value:6}
   },
   right:{
      value:10,
      right:{value:12}
   }
}
```

Which would be in image like this

[image]

I tried below code:

```
var arr = [8,10,12,5,3,6];
var root = arr[0];
var rv = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] < root){
    rv.left = arr[i];
  }else{
    rv.right = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log(rv);
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: And what is the output of the code you tried?

Answer (score 14):

You could use a `Node` instance for new nodes and a function for inserting nodes.

Then iterate the values and build a new tree.

```js
function Node(value) {
    this.value = value;
    // this.left = null;
    // this.right = null;
}

function insertNode(tree, value) {
    var node = tree,
        key;
    while (node.value !== value) {
         key = value < node.value ? 'left' : 'right';
         if (!node[key]) {
             node[key] = new Node(value);
             break;
         }
         node = node[key];
    }
    return tree;
}

var array = [8, 10, 12, 5, 3, 6],
    tree = array.reduce((t, v) => t ? insertNode(t, v) : new Node(v), null);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: you don't mention how the array should be serialized for this tree. Is it in order, postorder, preorder, or is it completely arbitrary?

Comment: @Rick, is it necessary?

Comment: In the code, from the tree can you convert it back to the original array as well? Otherwise, it seems like the tree and the array have no logical relationship to each other.

Answer (score 3):

While it is close to Nina's answer i believe to be a little more concise;

```js
var data = [8,10,12,5,3,6],
    tree;

function insertBinTree (t = {value: void 0, left: void 0, right: void 0}, n){
  t.value !== void 0 ? t.value > n ? t.left = insertBinTree(t.left,n)
                                   : t.right = insertBinTree(t.right,n)
                     : t.value = n;
  return t;
}

tree = data.reduce(insertBinTree, void 0);
console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this by recursive method

```js
var binary = {};
var arr = [8,5,10,3,6,12];

function makeBinary(binary,number){
  if(binary.value === undefined){
    binary.value = number;
  }else if(number > binary.value){
    if(binary.right === undefined){
      binary.right = {value:number};  
    }else{
      binary.right = makeBinary(binary.right,number);
    }
  }else{
    if(binary.left === undefined){
      binary.left = {value:number};  
    }else{
      binary.left = makeBinary(binary.left,number);
    }
  }
  return binary;
}

for(let i in arr){
  makeBinary(binary,arr[i]);
}

console.log(binary);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Node {
    constructor(val){
        this.val=val;
        this.right=null;
        this.left=null;
    }
}


class Bst{
    constructor(){
        this.root=null;
    }

    insert(val){
        let newNode= new Node (val)
        if (!this.root) this.root=newNode;
    let current =this.root;        
        while (true) {
            if(val === current.val) return undefined;
            if(current.val<val){
                if (current.right===null){
                    current.right=newNode;
                    return this
                }
                    else
                    current=current.right}
            if(current.val>val){
                if (current.left===null){
                    current.left=newNode;
                    return this
                }
                    else
                    current=current.left}
                
        }
        
    
    }
    print (){
        let all="Root=";
    let visit=(current=this.root)=>{
        if(!current.left && !current.right){
            if(all[all.length-1]<current.val)
                 all+=`,LeR${current.val}`
                 else
                 all+=`,LeL${current.val}`
                }
else{
    if(all[all.length-1]<current.val)
         all+=`,FR${current.val}`
         else
                  all+=`,FL${current.val}`
            }
       
   if (current.left) visit(current.left)
   if (current.right)  visit(current.right)
        }
        visit()
        all+=` ,valid bst:${this.isValidBST()}`
        return all

    }

 isValidBST(node=this.root, min = null, max = null) {
if (!node) return true;
if (max !== null && node.data >= max) {
  return false;
}
if (min !== null && node.data <= min) {
  return false;
}
const leftSide = this.isValidBST(node.left, min, node.data);
const rightSide = this.isValidBST(node.right, node.val, max);

return leftSide && rightSide;
    }

find(val){
    let found=false
    let innerFind=(current=this.root)=>{
    if (val>current.val) 
       if (current.right != null) return innerFind(current.right)
        if(val===current.val)
        found= true 
   else
      if (current.left != null)return innerFind(current.left)
        if(val===current.val)
            found= true 
    return found
        }
        return innerFind()
    }

}




let tree=new Bst

tree.insert(8)
tree.insert(10)
tree.insert(13)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(4)
tree.insert(7)
tree.insert(2)
tree.print()
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for answering. While this code might answer the question, can you consider adding some explanation for what the problem was you solved, and how you solved it? This will help future readers to understand your answer better and learn from it.

Comment: This implements a BST with functions like Insert print all and checking if valid BST and find(boolean but can be easily changed ) just copy and paste to console to see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by technique is called recursion.
make an array with the structure ( left_subtree, key, right_subtree)
in your case
var array = [[3,5,6],8,[null,10,12]

```js
class TreeNode {
    constructor(key) {
        this.key = key;
        this.right = null;
        this.left = null;
    }
}

function parseTuple(data) {
    if (data === null) {
        let node = null;
        return node;
    }
    else if (data.length === 3) {
        let node = new TreeNode(data[1]);
        node.left = parseTuple(data[0]);
        node.right = parseTuple(data[2]);
        return node;
    }
    else {
        let node = new TreeNode(data);
        return node;
    }

}
```